# How can I breed a Bloom Dragon?

Tags: dragonvale

I want to breed a Bloom Dragon. Which dragons should I breed and how will I know whether I got one? How long are they available?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A [**Bloom Dragon**](http://dragonvale.wikia.com/wiki/Bloom_Dragon) can be bred using **Storm + Lichen** dragons or any combination involving the elements **Plant, Cold and Lightning**. Storm + Plant or Lichen + storm also works.

You'll know you have a Bloom Dragon if you get a breeding time of **13 hours**. The egg will be rainbow colored.

Bloom dragons started appearing April 2nd and **will stop being availible after April 30th**. Breed your Bloom Dragons before then or you'll have to wait until next year.

If you breed two of them together you'll be able to breed new Bloom Dragons even after the event is over.

Comment: Plant and storm worked for me.

Comment: I made many attempts with Lichen+Lightning and Cactus+Cold with no success.  Storm+Lichen has worked 2 out of 4 times, with one of the other 2 unsuccessful attempts a Sun/Moon dragon that is still gestating.  Both of my successful attempts have been on the Breeding Island.

Comment: @EBongo I've actually heard people recommend against using the Breeding Island because of the chance of getting a sun/moon dragon

Comment: Plant and storm for me on the 5th try but after another 3 attempts still no second bloom .